# Sticky row in Visual Composer

Tags: css, sticky

I am making a site in Wordpress using the Visual Composer page builder.

I want to make a row sticky to the top of the page and have added this CSS to the editor:

```
/* makes header bar sticky to top of page */
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

and I have added sticky as the class name.

It's not working and I'm not sure where I am going wrong? Please help.

Thanks

Comment: did you mean, you want to top sticky menu bar? please give more example

Answer (score 0):

If you want that row to overlap everything, including the header, you have to move it within the DOM and append it to the body of the page. Otherwise, it becomes fixed within its parent container.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if (jQuery(".sticky").length) {
        jQuery(".sticky").appendTo("body");     
    }
});
```

Assuming the above is saved in a files called "my-scripts.js" in "js" directory inside your root theme folder, you can make sure you include the above code properly AFTER the jQuery library in WordPress with the function below:.

```
function my_jquery_scripts() {

    $PathToMyScript = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/my-scripts.js";

    wp_register_script('my-jquery-js', $PathToMyScript, array( 'jquery' ), time(), true);
    wp_enqueue_script('my-jquery-js');

} add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_jquery_scripts');
```

NB: If you want the browser to cache your script, replace `time()` with `false`.

Answer (score 0):

you can enable "sticky" in the parent row to fix this